# Torchvision's transforms.RandomRotation() is zeroing out my image tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library, torchvision

Every time I use `torchvision.transforms.RandomRotation` with `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor`, I get a zero'd out image tensor.
For example, if I run this on an image:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import  transforms

ROTATION_TRANSFORM = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.RandomRotation(30),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

NO_ROTATION_TRANSFORM = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

image = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
rotated_image_tensor = ROTATION_TRANSFORM(image)
image_tensor = NO_ROTATION_TRANSFORM(image)

print(rotated_image_tensor)
print(image_tensor)
```

I get this result:

```
tensor([[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         ...,
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]]])
tensor([[[0.5255, 0.5294, 0.5333,  ..., 0.4902, 0.4980, 0.4980],
         [0.5255, 0.5255, 0.5333,  ..., 0.4863, 0.4941, 0.4941],
         [0.5216, 0.5255, 0.5294,  ..., 0.4784, 0.4863, 0.4863],
         ...,
         [0.6275, 0.6353, 0.6471,  ..., 0.6275, 0.6431, 0.6510],
         [0.6196, 0.6275, 0.6431,  ..., 0.6549, 0.6471, 0.6392],
         [0.6392, 0.6471, 0.6549,  ..., 0.6667, 0.6431, 0.6275]],

        [[0.5255, 0.5294, 0.5333,  ..., 0.5216, 0.5294, 0.5294],
         [0.5255, 0.5255, 0.5333,  ..., 0.5176, 0.5255, 0.5255],
         [0.5216, 0.5255, 0.5294,  ..., 0.5098, 0.5176, 0.5176],
         ...,
         [0.6039, 0.6118, 0.6235,  ..., 0.6196, 0.6353, 0.6431],
         [0.5961, 0.6039, 0.6196,  ..., 0.6471, 0.6392, 0.6314],
         [0.6157, 0.6235, 0.6314,  ..., 0.6588, 0.6353, 0.6196]],

        [[0.5333, 0.5373, 0.5412,  ..., 0.5333, 0.5412, 0.5412],
         [0.5333, 0.5333, 0.5412,  ..., 0.5294, 0.5373, 0.5373],
         [0.5294, 0.5333, 0.5373,  ..., 0.5216, 0.5294, 0.5294],
         ...,
         [0.5569, 0.5647, 0.5765,  ..., 0.5725, 0.5882, 0.5961],
         [0.5490, 0.5569, 0.5725,  ..., 0.6000, 0.5922, 0.5843],
         [0.5686, 0.5765, 0.5843,  ..., 0.6118, 0.5882, 0.5725]]])
```

Isn't the image tensor losing information through this rotation? Why is it being zero'd out and how can I prevent that?

I also noticed that the result is last drastic when the amount of random rotation is reduced. For example, when I use `RandomRotation(10)`, I still see zeros, but less of them. I'm trying to use `RandomRotation` to data augment my training images for a classifier, but I feel like this zeroing out of the image tensors is hurting my data severely.

Comment: You are rotating the image and therefore there will be a black background when the image gets out of size. Try RandomRotation(1)